# creating several OpenGL widgets in QMainWindow

Tags: opengl, qt5, qwidget

I work with Qt5 and must code something like simple 3D-editor. I need to have 4 projection-views in my main window (for different scene-projections). 
I saw OpenGLWindow example, but there was only one window and i don't know how to modify it for my purpose.

There are next lines in example.

`class OpenGLWindow : public QWindow, protected QOpenGLFunctions
{
        ........
        private:
        QOpenGLContext *m_context;
}`

As Assistant says, QOpenGLContext can draw only on QSufrace, which is direct base of QWindow.

So, how can I put several projection-views on one MainWindow.

I need tools, contained in QOpenGLFunctions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to have one QOpenGLContext. Drawing multiple views is usually done by like this:

```
//Top Left
glViewport (0, windowHeight/2, windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2);
draw();

//Top Right
glViewport (windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2, windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2);
draw();

//Bottom Right
glViewport (windowWidth/2, 0, windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2); 
draw();

//Bottom Left
glViewport (0, 0, windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2);
draw();
```

Comment: hmmm, thanks, i thought about this idea. can you tell me where can i find some example for this ?

Comment: example isn't necessary more, i've found out how to do that)